# Trouble with my website form

Tags: php, html

I have the following form on each of my website pages:

```
<section class="footer-one">
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<div>
<div class="row half">

<div class="6u">
<input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="contact_phone" placeholder="מספר טלפון" onfocus="if (this.value == '                             טלפון נייד') this.value = '';"  onchange=" telephoneCheck1()"/>
</div>
<div class="6u">
<input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="contact_name" onfocus="if (this.value == '                             שם מלא') this.value = '';" onchange="nameCheck1" name="contact_name" placeholder="שם מלא" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row half">
<div class="12u"> 
<textarea name="message" id="comments" placeholder=" תוכן ההודעה"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="12u">
<ul class="actions">
  <li><input type="submit" class="button button-style1" value="שלח" /></li>
  <li><input type="reset" class="button button-style2" value="אפס" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</section>
```

it is connected to the following php:

```
<?php
header ('Location: http://www.intrahouse.co.il ');
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "danielko@intrahouse.co.il";
    $email_subject = "פנייה מהאתר";

    $first_name = $_POST['contact_name']; 
    $telephone = $_POST['contact_phone']; 
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; 

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
}
?>
```

there is also a jquery for spam checking:

```
var name_success = false;
var phone_success = false;

function validateForm()
{
if (name_success == true && phone_success == true)
{
alert("הפנייה נשלח בהצלח");
return true;
}
if (name_success == false)
{
alert("שגיאה, ציין שם ושם משפחה תקין");
return false;
}
if (phone_success == false)
{
alert("שגיאה, מספר הפלאפון שציינת אינו תקין");
return false;
 }
}

function nameCheck1(){
var reg=/\w{3,50}/;
var fname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;

if(reg.test(fname)){ 
        name_success = true;
}
else{
    alert("שגיאה, ציין שם ושם משפחה תקין");
    name_success = false;
}
} 


function telephoneCheck1(){
var telephone = document.getElementById("telephone").value;
var phone = telephone.replace(/\s|-/g,'');
var reg=/^\d+$/;
if(reg.test(phone)){
    phone_success = true;
}
else{
    alert("שגיאה, מספר הפלאפון שציינת אינו תקין");
    phone_success = false;
}
}
```

I'm missing something since it won't send me any emails... the form doesn't work :\
thanks

Comment: Why do you suppress error messages and then ask for help?

Comment: Remove the `@` from `@mail`

Answer (score 1):

You have no element with `name="email"`. As such, `isset($_POST['email'])` simply cannot be true, hence no email is sent.

Either add the `name` you are looking for, or look for a `name` that *does* exist.

Additionally, you have two `name="name"` elements (although the second one has a second `name` attribute... consider revising!)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
 <input type="text"
class="text"
name="name"
id="contact_phone"
placeholder=" מספר
```

טלפון ". onfocus="if
(this.value == '
טלפון נייד ')
    this.value = '';"
    onchange="
    telephoneCheck1()"/>
    
    
    
    this.value = '';"
    onchange="nameCheck1"
    name="contact_name"
    placeholder=" שם מלא " />

Change it to:

```
<input type="text" class="text".    name="contact_phone"
id="contact_phone"
placeholder=" מספר
```

טלפון " onfocus="if
    (this.value == '
טלפון נייד ')
    this.value = '';"
    onchange="
    telephoneCheck1()"/>

Answer (score 0):

Also your script is redirecting you to index page and try also the suggestion of niet th dark apostol suggested. Remove first line of script.php header or put it to some place taht makes sense.

Comment: "Niet the Dark Apostle"? That's a new one on me!

Comment: Hehe sorry about that :)